# Save svg state to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a SVG Editor and I was wondering how to save the svg canvas as a whole to the local storage.

Something similar to saving the data url of a raster canvas?

Comment: SVG can be saved as a string using `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: @evolutionxbox And what is the correct attribute/method to get this string?

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of this SVG canvas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.